# pgrouting is very slow

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, dijkstra

I have the following code but the output is empty. It is very slow. I want a pair to pair pgr_dijstracost rather than many to many. Is there a feasible solution?

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   ii int := 1;
BEGIN
   WHILE ii < 1396381
   LOOP
     INSERT INTO public.loop (start_vid,end_vid,agg_cost)
     Select * from pgr_dijkstraCost(
    'select gid as id, source, target, length as cost from table1'
    ,(select table1.source from table1 Inner join table2 on table2.segment = table1.segment where table2.id = ii)
    ,(select table1.target from table1Inner join table2 on table2.segment2= table1.segment where table2.id = ii)
    ,false);
    ii := ii + 1;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Comment: If there is an empy result and not an error, then this usually means that there is no route. Are you sure `source` and `target` ID exist in your network table?

Comment: I just checked and edited the query but I have a major issue. I want to run the scrip in pair to pair instead of Array to Array (aka Many to Many). Is there a possible solution?

The network consists of around 250000 edges and my laptop cannot handle this big amount of values. Therefore, I included only the areas of interest in a separate table.

I modified the script above to reflect a loop, but it is very very slow. Do you know of any solution?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to make many requests with a single query but not a full matrix, then look at the very new "combinations" addition for pgr_dijkstra https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html

Comment: This is a better link https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#combinations . The functionality was just added recently. Making individiual queries for the amount of cominations you have will take a lot of time and will be inefficient.